# Database Design - Cardinality

Tags: database-design

I am currently studying for my MTA Database Fundamentals cert, and I came across this question during my studies.  However, the answer doesn't make any sense to me.  Here is the question/answer:
[image]

It is my understanding that 'cardinality' defines the relationship of the database entities, such as if the relationship is `1:1`, `1:many`, or `many:many`.  How does removing a row affect the cardinality of this database entity at all?

Question/Answer source is from EnsurePass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may be referring to cardinality as in the number of rows within the table.  This link has an explanation of each definition of cardinality in a database:

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/cardinality-in-sql/

Comment: Interesting, that didn't come up in the Microsoft-approved textbook at all.  Thanks for the resource.

Comment: The cardinality of a table is also defined in the SQL standard (as the number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

Cardinality in this sense refers to the number of unique values, usually when referring to a column.

For example, in a table containing information about employees, the gender column would be said to have low-cardinality (few distinct values, repeated many times) whereas telephone number would have high-cardinality (many unique values).

It seems odd to me that they're talking about the cardinality of the table as a whole here, but they're referring to the number of unique rows.

Comment: No, the question clearly states "cardinality of the **table**". It's the number of rows. Unique or not, it doesn't matter. If the table has a (any) unique constraint, it's of course the same thing. But tables do not have to have a unique constraint.